# Format number with thousand separator and 1 decimal behind comma

Tags: vb.net

I am looking for a custom format i think ?

I a TextBox a number for example like this `10097` and the outcome has to have a thousand separator and decimal with one number behind the comma.

Looking for this outcome `1.009,7`

Any one has a link or answer because i  can't find this format.

I forgot , i live in Europe

Comment: Need it to put it in form field in a PDF , normaly it is 1,0097 that is no problem but don't know why they want to change it to 1.009,7

Comment: So `10097` is actually `1009,7`? According to what rules?

Comment: Is it always that *integer* divided by `10`?

Comment: Thanks for the reply . 1,0097 is the Density of Oil , for all the other company's this is the right number format. But only this one has to be different in format .

Comment: I think i found something , comment of Jimi with divided by 10 and Format of N1 in the answer of Tim Schmelter. When i do a calculation of 10097 / 10 the outcome in format "N1 "is what i am looking for 1.009,7

Answer (score 1):

If `10097` that was a typo(more than ten thousand) and actually is:

```
Dim number As Int32 = 1097 ' so parse the TextBox-value to Integer first
```

It works to use the [numeric format specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#NFormatString) `"N1"`:

```
Dim result As String = number.ToString("N1") ' 1.097,0
```